# Select one check box from pop up window and close it with a button using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is like this:

when clicking on some link it will appear the popup window. In that window there are some assignments behind the check box. I want to select one assignment per once and assignment should be given assignment. It means that if I want to select "Assignment01" I can be any where of that window. But I want to the select that assignment by name using and click "okay" button selenium webdriver.

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding the screenshot, add the HTML . And what have you tried so far for this? What is the issue you're facing.

Comment: Add html. Maybe You have to switch your focus, maybe its frame, provide html. Usually its nested so first You have to find checkbox control, than afterwards nested elements, and them click on desired one.